Why is the trace of this matrix equal to the squared Frobenius norm?
Suppose $A$ is a $d\times d$ matrix formed by multiplying $d$ random matrices of the form $I-vv^T$ where $v$ is sampled isotropically from the unit sphere.
It appears that various various values of $d$, $\operatorname{Tr}(A)$ and $\|A\|_F^2$ are almost equal, how can we explain this fact?

Background:

spectrum of this matrix is visualized here, this matrix is highly non-normal
singular values also appear to work to compute higher spectral moments, discussed here.

Notebook

Is $v'$ the transpose of the column vector $v$?

@CyclotomicField yes

These numbers are getting suspiciously close to $e^{-1}$

@whpowell96 I can show that expected trace is equal to $(1-1/d)^d$, but I don't understand why squared Frobenius norm also has this value

I see. This is a very interesting problem! Could you try to visualize the densities of $Re(\lambda_i)$ and $\sigma_i^2$? The results seem to indicate that they have the same mean as $d\to\infty$, but it may be that the densities share more similarities asymptotically

@whpowell96 I visualize absolute values of eigenvalues and squared singular values in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5015510/when-are-spectral-moments-equal-to-sums-of-powers-of-singular-values

Densities seem different, ie the matrix has negative eigenvalues, so it needs to have larger positive eigenvalues to balance the sum out, since square singular values are only positive

So there are two distinct distributions with the same mean. That is odd. When I get some time I will play around with this construction to see what sort of tweaks break this equivalence

@Jap88 individual projection matrices don't commute so their product is not a projection

It is easy to show that the $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ and $\|A\|_F^2=\operatorname{tr}(A'A)$ have the same mean $d(1-\frac{1}{d})^d$. The hard part, which I am not able to answer here, is whether (or why) the distributions of $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ and $\|A\|_F^2$ are highly concentrated about their common mean.
Let $P_i=I-v_iv_i'$ where $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_d$ be independently and uniformly sampled from the unit sphere. Consider any matrix product of the form $P_{j_1}P_{j_2}\cdots P_{j_k}$. For every constant unitary matrix $Q$, since $Qv_1$ has the same distribution as $v_i$, we have
$$
E(P_{j_1}P_{j_2}\cdots P_{j_k})
=E\left((QP_{j_1}Q')(QP_{j_2}Q')\cdots (Q'P_{j_k}Q)\right)
=QE(P_{j_1}P_{j_2}\cdots P_{j_k})Q'.
$$
That is, $E(P_{j_1}P_{j_2}\cdots P_{j_k})$ is invariant under every unitary similarity transform. Hence it must be a scalar multiple of $I$.
In particular, as $E(P_i)=E(I-v_iv_i')$ has trace $d-1$, it must be equal to $cI$ where $c=1-\frac{1}{d}$. Hence
\begin{align*}
E(A)
&=E\left(P_1P_2\cdots P_d\right)\\
&=E(P_1)E(P_2)\cdots E(P_d)\\
&=c^dI,\\
E\left(AA'\right)
&=E\left(P_1P_2\cdots P_{d-1}P_dP_dP_{d-1}\cdots P_1\right)\\
&=E\left(P_1P_2\cdots P_{d-1}P_dP_{d-1}\cdots P_1\right)\\
&=E\left(P_1P_2\cdots P_{d-1}E(P_d)P_{d-1}\cdots P_1\right)\\
&=E\left(P_1P_2\cdots P_{d-1}(cI)P_{d-1}\cdots P_2P_1\right)\\
&=cE\left(P_1P_2\cdots P_{d-1}P_{d-1}\cdots P_2P_1\right)\\
&=\cdots\\
&=c^dE(I)=c^dI.
\end{align*}
It follows that $E(\operatorname{tr}(A))=dc^d=E(\operatorname{tr}(AA'))=E(\|A\|_F^2)$

In the linked posts, there are some visualizations of the eigenvalue and singular value distributions for a matrix with $d=40000$ and they appear to only concentrate about 0 and 1, not the mean.

With 'slightly more intensive' computations, one can write the expression of Var(tr(A)) out and show the concentration (Var(tr(A) / d) -> 0)

@XiangxiangXu That’s great. Would you like to write it out in an answer?

@user1551 I wish it were some stupid error, but it seems my Var(tr(A)) converges to a constant (without being scaled by $d$)... That seems to be a very strong concentration (see below).

We can abstract each update as $$B = (I - vv^T) A,\tag{*}$$ where $v$ is chosen from the unit hypersphere independent of the choices of $A$. Our derivation will use the following facts:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[vv^T] = \frac{1}{d} \cdot I, \qquad \mathbb{E}[(v^TMv)^2] =
\frac{1}{d(d+2)} \left[\operatorname{tr}^2(M) + \operatorname{tr}(M^TM)+ \operatorname{tr}(M^2)\right]
\end{align}.
$$

From (*) we get
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}(B) &= \operatorname{tr}(A) - v^TAv
\end{align}
$$ and $$\operatorname{tr}^2(B) = \operatorname{tr}^2(A) - 2 \operatorname{tr}(A) \cdot v^TAv + (v^TAv)^2.$$
Taking the conditional expectation, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(B)|A] = \left(1-\frac{2}{d}\right)\operatorname{tr}^2(A) + \frac{1}{d(d+2)}\left[\operatorname{tr}^2(A) + \operatorname{tr}(A^TA)+ \operatorname{tr}(A^2)\right].\tag{1}
$$
Similarly, as $B^2 = (I - vv^T) A(I - vv^T) A = A^2 - vv^T A^2 - Avv^TA + vv^TAvv^TA$, we have
$$\operatorname{tr}(B^2) = \operatorname{tr}(A^2) - 2v^TA^2v + (v^TAv)^2$$
and
$$\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(B^2)|A] = \left(1-\frac{2}{d}\right)\operatorname{tr}(A^2) + \frac{1}{d(d+2)} \left[\operatorname{tr}^2(A) + \operatorname{tr}(A^TA)+ \operatorname{tr}(A^2)\right].\tag{2}$$
Also, since $B^TB = A^T(I-vv^T)A = A^TA - A^Tvv^TA$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(B^TB)|A] = \left(1-\frac{1}{d}\right) \operatorname{tr}(A^TA) .\tag{3}$$

Taking another expectation of (1)-(3), we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(B)]\\
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(B^2)]\\
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(B^TB)]
\end{bmatrix}
= C
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(A)]\\
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(A^2)]\\
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)]
\end{bmatrix},\qquad
C = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{2}{d} + \frac{1}{d(d+2)} & \frac{1}{d(d+2)} & \frac{1}{d(d+2)}\\
\frac{1}{d(d+2)} & 1-\frac{2}{d} + \frac{1}{d(d+2)} & \frac{1}{d(d+2)}\\
0 & 0 & 1-\frac{1}{d}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The matrix $C$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 1-\frac{2}{d}+ \frac{2}{d(d+2)}, \lambda_2 = 1-\frac{2}{d}, \lambda_3 = 1-\frac{1}{d}$, with corresponding eigenvectors $(1, 1, 0)^T, (1, -1, 0)^T, (1, 1, d)^T$.
The initial condition is $A = I$, and $\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(A)]\\
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(A^2)]\\
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)]
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}d^2\\ d\\ d\end{bmatrix} = \frac{d^2 + d - 2}{2}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} + \frac{d^2 - d}{2}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ d\end{bmatrix} $.

Therefore, after iterating $d$-steps, we obtain the result
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(A)] &= \frac{d^2 + d - 2}{2} \cdot \lambda_1^d + \frac{d^2 - d}{2} \cdot \lambda_2^d + \lambda_3^d\\
&= \frac{d^2 + d - 2}{2} \cdot \left(1-\frac{2}{d}+ \frac{2}{d(d+2)}\right)^d + \frac{d^2 - d}{2} \cdot \left(1-\frac{2}{d}\right)^d + \left(1-\frac{1}{d}\right)^d.\end{align}
$$
As $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(A)] = \left(1-\frac{1}{d}\right)^d d$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(\operatorname{tr}(A)) &= 
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(A)]
-
(\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(A)])^2 \\
&=
\frac{d^2 + d - 2}{2} \cdot \left(1-\frac{2}{d}+ \frac{2}{d(d+2)}\right)^d + \frac{d^2 - d}{2} \cdot \left(1-\frac{2}{d}\right)^d + \left(1-\frac{1}{d}\right)^d - \left(1-\frac{1}{d}\right)^{2d} d^2.
\end{align}
$$
which has a constant limit $\frac{-3 + 2 e}{2 e^2}$from Wolfram Alpha.

Remarks:

This approach can be extended to analyze the variance of $\operatorname{var}(\|A\|_F^2) = \operatorname{var}(\operatorname{tr}(A^TA))$, which converges to $1/e^2$ (see below);
As a byproduct, we also get

$$
\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(A^2)] &= \frac{d^2 + d - 2}{2} \left(1-\frac{2}{d}+ \frac{2}{d(d+2)}\right)^d - \frac{d^2 - d}{2}\left(1-\frac{2}{d}\right)^d + \left(1-\frac{1}{d}\right)^d\\
&= \frac{2d}{e^2} + \frac{e - 3}{e^2} + O\left(\frac1d\right)
\end{align}
\tag{P1} $$
(asymptotic from Wolfram Alpha)

On $\operatorname{var}(\operatorname{tr}(A^TA))$:
Since $$B^TB = A^T(I-vv^T)A = A^TA - A^Tvv^TA,\tag{#}$$ we have $
\operatorname{tr}(B^TB) = \operatorname{tr}(A^TA) - v^TAA^Tv$, and
$\operatorname{tr}^2(B^TB) = \operatorname{tr}^2(A^TA) - 2 \operatorname{tr}(A^TA) \cdot v^TAA^Tv + (v^TAA^Tv)^2.
$
Therefore,
$$
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(B^TB)|A]
= \left(1 - \frac{2}{d}\right)\operatorname{tr}^2(A^TA) + \frac{1}{d(d+2)} \left[\operatorname{tr}^2(A^TA) + 2\operatorname{tr}((A^TA)^2)\right].
$$
Similarly, from (#), we obtain
$$\begin{align}(B^TB)^2 &= (A^TA - A^Tvv^TA)(A^TA - A^Tvv^TA) \\
&= (A^TA)^2 - A^TAA^Tvv^TA - A^Tvv^TAA^TA + (A^Tvv^TA)^2
\end{align}$$ and thus
$$\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}((B^TB)^2)|A]
=
\left(1 - \frac{2}{d}\right)\operatorname{tr}((A^TA)^2) + \frac{1}{d(d+2)} \left[\operatorname{tr}^2(A^TA) + 2\operatorname{tr}((A^TA)^2)\right].
$$

Taking another expectation, we obtain
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(B^TB)]\\
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}((B^TB)^2)]
\end{bmatrix}
= C'
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(A^TA)]\\
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}((A^TA)^2)]
\end{bmatrix},\qquad
C' = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{2}{d} + \frac{1}{d(d+2)} & \frac{2}{d(d+2)} \\
\frac{1}{d(d+2)} & 1-\frac{2}{d} + \frac{2}{d(d+2)} 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The matrix $C'$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 1-\frac{2}{d} + \frac{3}{d(d+2)}, \lambda_2 = 1-\frac{2}{d}$, and corresponding eigenvectors
$(1, 1)^T$ and $(2, -1)^T$.
The initial condition is $ A = I$ and
$\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(A^TA)]\\
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}((A^TA)^2)]
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
d^2\\d
\end{bmatrix}
= \frac{d^2+2d}{3}
\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix}
+ \frac{d^2-d}{3}
\begin{bmatrix} 2\\-1\end{bmatrix}
$.

Therefore, after iterating $d$-steps, we obtain the result
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(A^TA)] &= 
\frac{d^2+2d}{3}
\left(1-\frac{2}{d} + \frac{3}{d(d+2)}\right)^d
+ 2 \cdot \frac{d^2-d}{3} \left(1-\frac{2}{d}\right)^d
.\end{align}
$$
As $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)] = \left(1-\frac{1}{d}\right)^d d$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)) &= 
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}^2(A^TA)]
-
(\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)])^2 \\
&=
\frac{d^2+2d}{3}
\left(1-\frac{2}{d} + \frac{3}{d(d+2)}\right)^d
+ 2 \cdot \frac{d^2-d}{3} \left(1-\frac{2}{d}\right)^d - \left(1-\frac{1}{d}\right)^{2d} d^2.
\end{align}
$$
which has a constant limit $1/e^2$ from Wolfram Alpha.
We also get
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}((A^TA)^2)] &= 
\frac{d^2+2d}{3}
\left(1-\frac{2}{d} + \frac{3}{d(d+2)}\right)^d
- \frac{d^2-d}{3} \left(1-\frac{2}{d}\right)^d\\
&= \frac{2d}{e^2} -\frac{1}{2e^2} + O\left(\frac1d\right)
,\end{align}\tag{P2}
$$
(asymptotic from Wolfram Alpha)
We can compare (P2) with (P1) and show their expectations have the same linear term. This is related to the case $p = 2$ discussed in this post "Why is $\operatorname{Tr}(A^p)\approx \sum_i \sigma_i^{2p}$ for this random matrix?".

Thanks for your work. It’s very nice! By the way, how do you obtain the formula
$E[(v^TMv)^2] = \frac{1}{d(d+2)} \left[\operatorname{tr}^2(M) + \operatorname{tr}(M^TM)+ \operatorname{tr}(M^2)\right]$. I can use $E[v^Tvv^Tv]=1$ and the invariance of $E[(v^TMv)^2]$ under orthogonal similarity to set up two linear equations in $a=E[v_1^2]$ and $b=E[v_1^2v_2^2]$ and obtain the formula without difficulty, but I have not seen this formula before. Is it well-known in the literature? Any reference?

impressive; it may be helpful to note that the $v$'s have the same distribution as the matrix elements in a single row (or single column) of a $d\times d$ orthogonal random matrix with Haar measure, and in that context the formula is well known, in the form $\mathbb{E}[[v_i v_j v_k v_l] = \frac{1}{d(d+2)}[\delta_{ij} \delta_{kl} + \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl} + \delta_{il} \delta_{jk}]$.

more general formulas of this type follow from Weingarten calculus

@user1551 It can be done by applying the result of $\mathbb{E}[v_iv_jv_kv_l]$ (as pointed out in the above cmts), and the only non-trivial cases are $\mathbb{E}[v_1^4]$ and $\mathbb{E}[v_1^2v_2^2]$.

the generalization to higher powers seems to be of the form $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}A^p]=\frac{dp^{p-1}}{(p-1)!e^p}+{\cal O}(d^0)$; I still need to check that this also agrees with $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{tr}(A^\top A)^p]$.

@CarloBeenakker Your formula well matches the one plotted in the other post in the case $d = 100$.  The $(p-1)!$ could be extended to $\Gamma(p)$.
